# Bootstrap navbar menu logo not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please take a look on this **[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/evvyTUumtI)** or below **Code Snippet**, I am using Bootstrap 3.1 because I want to use this awesome search box on my site. But I am having a issue, the navbar logo is not working (it's not even hovering so it's not clickable).

[image]

**Note: Brand logo is working fine in mobile version, only having issue in desktop versions. So, if you are running below code snippet, click Full Screen to see the problem.**

I am not a css guy, so can you guys please help me how to fix this.
Thanks

```js
$(function () {
        // Remove Search if user Resets Form or hits Escape!
  $('body, .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"]').on('click keyup', function(event) {
   console.log(event.currentTarget);
   if (event.which == 27 && $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]').hasClass('active') ||
    $(event.currentTarget).attr('type') == 'reset') {
    closeSearch();
   }
  });

  function closeSearch() {
            var $form = $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active')
      $form.find('input').val('');
   $form.removeClass('active');
  }

  // Show Search if form is not active // event.preventDefault() is important, this prevents the form from submitting
  $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]:not(.active) button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
    $input = $form.find('input');
   $form.addClass('active');
   $input.focus();

  });
  // ONLY FOR DEMO // Please use $('form').submit(function(event)) to track from submission
  // if your form is ajax remember to call `closeSearch()` to close the search container
  $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
    $input = $form.find('input');
   $('#showSearchTerm').text($input.val());
            closeSearch()
  });
    });
```

```css
body {
  padding: 60px 0px;
 }

 .navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px !important;
  max-height: 270px;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
  background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
  border-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
  box-shadow: none;
 }
 .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"] {
  display: none;
 }

 @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
   padding-top: 0px !important;
   padding-right: 38px !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
   width: 38px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
   padding: 15px 12px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
   font-size: 18pt;
   opacity: 0;
   display: none;            
            height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
   width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
   display: table-cell;
   opacity: 1;
  }
     .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
   width: 100%;
  }
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.google.com">Brand Logo</a>

        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" class="">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#" class="">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"> <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
         <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
         <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
</span>
                    </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;"> <strong class="">Alerts Dont Work on Bootsnipp!</strong> So when you hit
            enter or submit this form your result will show up in the green box below!</div>
        <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;"> <strong class="">Your Result!</strong>  <span id="showSearchTerm" class=""></span>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a copy of your html we can peek at?

Comment: @oMiKeY: I just updated my question with code snippet. can you please check it again. Thanks

Comment: and what is the expected action when the button is clicked on? its href seems just to be '#'

Comment: @oMiKeY: it's just any link and I just update it with google link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have put in too much effort already. So I have a CSS hack for your problem.

To prioritize the logo over other elements.

**Add**

```
.navbar-brand {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Now for the search to override/prioritize over the logo when expanded,

**Change**

```
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  // Remove Search if user Resets Form or hits Escape!
  $('body, .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"]').on('click keyup', function(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    if (event.which == 27 && $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]').hasClass('active') ||
      $(event.currentTarget).attr('type') == 'reset') {
      closeSearch();
    }
  });

  function closeSearch() {
    var $form = $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active')
    $form.find('input').val('');
    $form.removeClass('active');
  }

  // Show Search if form is not active // event.preventDefault() is important, this prevents the form from submitting
  $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]:not(.active) button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
      $input = $form.find('input');
    $form.addClass('active');
    $input.focus();

  });
  // ONLY FOR DEMO // Please use $('form').submit(function(event)) to track from submission
  // if your form is ajax remember to call `closeSearch()` to close the search container
  $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
      $input = $form.find('input');
    $('#showSearchTerm').text($input.val());
    closeSearch()
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 60px 0px;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px !important;
  max-height: 270px;
}
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
  background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
  border-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
  box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"] {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-brand {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 38px !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
    width: 38px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    padding: 15px 12px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    font-size: 18pt;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
    display: table-cell;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.google.com">Brand Logo</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"> <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
         <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </span>
          </button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
         <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
            </span>
          </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;"> <strong class="">Alerts Dont Work on Bootsnipp!</strong> So when you hit enter or submit this form your result will show up in the green box below!</div>
    <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;"> <strong class="">Your Result!</strong>  <span id="showSearchTerm" class=""></span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help, Arbaz :)